# Error al serializar array a partir de un enlace en PHP

Tags: php, array, serialización

El array me lo crea bien pero a la hora de serializar no entiendo porque me da ese fallo.
Si alguien puede decir donde está el error me sería de mucha ayuda, creo que mi fallo está en que no entiendo bien el paso de arrays entre páginas de PHP...

La linea 67 es el: <a href="ej3.php"...>

La siguiente imagen es el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
<body>
    <h1>Averigua la imagen oculta</h1>
    <?php 
        //Hecho con tabla background-img y celdas con visible o gris
        //Tabla 10x10
        //Limite de intentos
        //Resultado en otra página
        //Almacenar en un array la situación de cada celda (vista u oculta) 
        //y pasar el array con la función serialize para mayor comodidad.

        if (isset($_REQUEST['panel'])) {
            $panel=unserialize(base64_decode($_REQUEST['panel']));
        }else{
            $panel=array_fill(0, 100, 'oculto');
        }

        print_r($panel);
        $n=0;
        echo "<table class='img-table'>";
        for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($j=0; $j < 10; $j++) { 
                echo "<td id='$panel[$n]'>
                    <a href='ej3.php?panel=base64_encode(serialize($panel))' style='width:100%; height: 100%; display:block'></a>
                </td>";
                $n++;
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
    <form action="ej3res.php" method="post" style="margin-top: 1rem;">
        <label for="respuesta">¿Qué imagen es?</label>
        <input type="text" name="respuesta" id="respuesta">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar respuesta">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea `67` en tu código? Haz un `var_dump` de la variable que tienes en esa línea y dinos qué muestra pulsando en editar. En vez de capturas de pantalla pon el texto con lo que se imprime, sea resultado de `var_dump`, sea mensajes de error.

Comment: Al generar la tabla, haces una llamada a $panel[$n], pero no veo en el código ninguna referencia a ese $n. Donde lo defines o tienes pensado añadirlo?

Comment: @A.Cedano La linea 67 es el: <a href="ej3.php"...> Hay un print_r($panel); de esa variable, se muestra al principio de la captura.

Comment: @Jakala esta justo debajo del print_r($panel);

Comment: En lugar de un `print_r($panel);` pon un `var_dump($panel);` y agrega la salida **como texto** en la pregunta para analizar la estructura. Una captura de imagen no sirve para que podamos analizar o indentar una estructura de datos. El error dice claramente que intentas leer un array como si fuese un string.

Comment: El problema se debe a que estas imprimiendo la variable `$panel` dentro de la cadena. Deberías concatenar la así `href='ej3.php?panel=".base64_encode(serialize($panel))."'`

Comment: @Marcos Era esto! muchísimas gracias aun soy muy inexperto y tengo errores muy tontos... Gracias por pararte a ayudarme!

Comment: @A.Cedano y Jakala Igualmente muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda intentaré tener en cuenta vuestros consejos y mejorar!

Comment: En PHP ciertas concatenaciones producen un código ilegible y difícil de depurar. Para casos como este, usar `printf` puede ayudar a escribir un código más claro. Por ejemplo, puedes cambiar el `echo` de tu `td` por esto: `printf("<td id=\"%s\"><a href=\"ej3.php?panel=%s\" style=\"width:100%%; height: 100%%; display:block\"></a></td>",$panel[$n],base64_encode(serialize($panel)));` Aquí hay menos confusión, simplemente, dentro de la cadena pones marcadores (`%s`)  en este caso, y las variables van como segundo parámetro. Y, puedes ver más fácil posibles fallos lógicos ...

Comment: ... por ejemplo, aquí se ve que tu etiqueta <a></a> no tiene nada por fuera, por lo que será un enlace que no mostrará nada donde hacer click, a no ser que hagas otro tratamiento, aplicando estilos o de otro modo. Por cierto, poner estilos in-line se considera una mala práctica. El código escrito así es difícil de mantener (debes editar todos los html en caso de algún cambio en esos estilos) y ensucia el código. Conviene usar reglas definidas en clases en un archivo `.css` Con respecto a eso mismo, hay un trato particular aquí: se dobla el valor `%` dado que `printf` lo usa como marcador.

Comment: @A.Cedano mañana en cuanto esté con el ordenador mejoraré el código y empezaré a usar el printf. Tienes toda la razón es muy mala práctica usar estilos en el propio HTML la verdad que al estar practicando PHP dejé de lado las buenas costumbres. Así que procuraré mejorar el código y mantener las buenas costumbres. Muchísimas gracias por todo lo que me has enseñado. ¡Espero poder enseñarte un código más bonito mañana cuando lo mejore!